# How can I fix Python version mismatch of Apache mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I am getting this error:

```
[Thu Jul 12 14:31:36 2012] [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.6.7', found '2.6.8'.
```

while trying to start Apache server. In a question, someone advised to rebuild mod_python for the correct version of Python. But mod_python is not supported anymore. So how can I use Python 2.7 or 2.6 with mod_wsgi and fix that error?

Comment: what operating system are you using for apache?

Comment: I am using Unix OS in Amazon EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I removed mod_python modules from python.conf. And rebuilt mod_wsgi. Now it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally minor versions don't require a rebuild, but in this case, you may need to rebuild mod_wsgi. You might need uninstall and reinstall the package. I think the person who recommended that you rebuild mod_python was confused; this was the package that was deprecated in favor of mod_wsgi.

Comment: I removed mod_python. Now Everything seems to be fine. But still I am getting Internal Error. My log is: [Thu Jul 12 16:06:07 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jul 12 16:06:07 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jul 12 16:06:07 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Jul 12 16:06:07 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations . But in the browser, I see the Internal Error message

Comment: The specific message he is getting is from mod_python and not mod_wsgi, so rebuilding mod_wsgi would not have helped. Differences in minor version do require a rebuild. It is only a patch level revision which doesn't and that is only true if Python was installed with a shared library and mod_python or mod_wsgi was using that shared library.