# python manage.py syncdb errors

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, python-2.7, django-models

I guys when run the command python manage.py syncdb i have the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 469, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.db import models

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if settings.DATABASES and DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 152, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Someone can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's all here:
The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty. [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#secret-key-setting-is-required)

Set the value SECRET_KEY

Comment: Ok I understood the problem but I don't know how to generate this key and to fill this key.

Comment: @Gabe. It should have been auto-generated but you can make one yourself: just a long string of random characters. Here's an example which you'd add to your settings.py:

Comment: SECRET_KEY = '*lk^6@0l0(iulgar$j)fbvfy&^(^u+qk3j73d18@&+ur^xuTxY'

Comment: Sorry Noel, can you specify the path where i can find settings.py          Thank you!!!

Comment: @Gabe It should be in the root folder of your Django project, where the manage.py file is. If you don't have this either, you probably need to generate the project using the command "django-admin.py startproject my_new_django_site" and put your django code in the folder it makes

Comment: @Gabe follow this tutorial for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Thank you Noel ni solved the problem with SECRET_KEY, but now i have problem with apache. if i post error logs con i help me?                                    [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.7.2+', found '2.7.3'.                                                            [error] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.     [error] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:$                                  Thak you very very much!!!

Comment: @Gabe Well I don't know but it sounds like it might be something like this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454264/how-can-i-fix-python-version-mismatch-of-apache-mod-wsgi

Comment: @Gabe That's if you're developing using mod_python on apache. If so, you'd be better to build your app using the webserver that comes with Django. That tutorial explains how to run the webserver: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server